# 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I know there are other questions similar to this but none of answer my questions below.

So i have a ViewController with layout defined in a XIB. From another ViewController i want to do something like this

```
let destVc = DestViewController(model:someModelData)
self.showViewController(destVc,...)
```

and DestViewController is Defined as followed:

```
class DestViewController : UITableViewController {
    var model: SomeModelData {
        didSet {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    init(model: SomeModelData) {
        self.model = model
        super.init(style: .Plain)

    }

   //...implementation below
}
```

The reason i want to do this this way is because

1) I dont want to have to use optionals or implicitly unwrapped optionals for my model data that this view controller definately needs, in fact this model data forms part of its contract

2) Which brings me on to the other benifit that having the model in the initialiser, it defines a clear contract to anyone want to create one of these ViewControllers, reinforced by swift's strong type system.

The problem is that this doesnt compile, xcode says:

```
 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of UIViewController
```

Which is really wierd because in the docs for UIViewController it doesn't declare init(coder) as a 'required' initialiser, it is a designated initialiser yes but there is no where in the [swift manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) that says i must override designated initialisers only required ones.

What is going on here why do i need to add:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

}
```

To make it work?

Note here is the swift doc for UITableViewController that appears in xcode when i cmd click it. Note the *lack* of 'required' before initWithCoder

```
public class UITableViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    public init(style: UITableViewStyle)
    public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)
    public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)

    public var tableView: UITableView!
    @available(iOS 3.2, *)
    public var clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear: Bool // defaults to YES. If YES, any selection is cleared in viewWillAppear:

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you override any of class's "designated" initializers,Though you don't inherit any other designated initializers. But because UIView adopts the NSCoding protocol,

which requires an init(coder:) initializer. That's why you need to implement `init(coder:)`

```
init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: decoder)
}
```

Comment: The NScoding protocol does not say required for this initialiser, if my superclass provides it why do i need to do it?

Comment: if someday somebody subclass your class... and if that class instance is initialised using init(coder) compiler will have hierarchy to executed